# Paypal Label missing in onepage checkout

Tags: magento, paypal

I just upgraded from magento 1.4.0 to 1.6. I have 2 payment methods: paypal and credit/debit card.

My issue is that whilst I am getting the credit/debit card text next to the relevant radio button, I am NOT getting any paypal text (the label) next to the paypal radio button. I have a description in the title in paypal config but this is not getting picked up.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't seem to relate to software development.

Comment: I have the same issue. It does relate to software development b/c the solution is mostly likely digging into Magento's code to add the label back in.

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't the ideal answer, here's the quick fix I used to manually add in the label. Go to `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/mark.phtml`. I edited this file, simply adding a text label before the PayPal image:

```
<!-- PayPal Logo -->
Credit Card / PayPal &nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getPaymentAcceptanceMarkSrc())?>" alt="<?php echo Mage::helper('paypal')->__('Acceptance Mark') ?>" class="v-middle" />&nbsp;
<a href="<?php echo $this->getPaymentAcceptanceMarkHref()?>" onclick="javascript:window.open('<?php echo $this->getPaymentAcceptanceMarkHref()?>','olcwhatispaypal','toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, ,left=0, top=0, width=400, height=350'); return false;"><?php echo Mage::helper('paypal')->__('What is PayPal?') ?></a>
<!-- PayPal Logo -->
```

Optionally, copy that file to `app/design/frontend/default/yourtemplatedir/template/mark.phtml` if you don't want your change to be overridden in the next upgrade.

The ideal solution would be to find the file that creates the label in the first place and make the change there. Also, using the method that gets the PayPal title set in the configuration setting. But the above is the first, quick fix I found that works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the `mark.phtml` file, I prerer to avoid displaying that file.

I copied the block `app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Block\Standard\Form.php` to my local (`app\code\local\...`) and changed

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_config = Mage::getModel('paypal/config')->setMethod($this->getMethodCode());
    $locale = Mage::app()->getLocale();
    $mark = Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('core/template');
    $mark = new $mark;
    $mark->setTemplate('paypal/payment/mark.phtml')
        ->setPaymentAcceptanceMarkHref($this->_config->getPaymentMarkWhatIsPaypalUrl($locale))
        ->setPaymentAcceptanceMarkSrc($this->_config->getPaymentMarkImageUrl($locale->getLocaleCode()))
    ; // known issue: code above will render only static mark image
    $this->setTemplate('paypal/payment/redirect.phtml')
        ->setRedirectMessage(
            Mage::helper('paypal')->__('You will be redirected to the PayPal website when you place an order.')
        )
        ->setMethodTitle('') // Output PayPal mark, omit title
        ->setMethodLabelAfterHtml($mark->toHtml())
    ;
    return parent::_construct();
}
```

to

```
... the same
...
    $this->setTemplate('paypal/payment/redirect.phtml')
        ->setRedirectMessage(
            Mage::helper('paypal')->__('You will be redirected to the PayPal website when you place an order.')
        )
        ->setMethodTitle('Paypal (my title)');
    return parent::_construct();
}
```

adding my custom title and removing the mark file.